# how to set class property while DeserializeObject in JsonNet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, json.net

Am trying to set class property  during DeserializeObject in json NET
to set email value to be UpperCase but its not working from the constructor

here is my code:

//account class

```
 public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public Account()
    {
        Email = Email.ToUpper();
    }

}
```

////button click events

```
  string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
   'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z'
     }";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

MessageBox.Show(account.Email);//printed james@example.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private string _email;
public string Email 
{ 
   get{
       return _email;

    }
   set
   {
     this._email = value.ToUpper();
   }
}
```